# How come some of my user fields get remember & pre-populated and others don't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on an app where people can go to edit their user and upon submission it redirects them to their show profile view.

This all seems to work according to plan but for some reason some when I go back to my edit view I see that some of my form fields get automatically pre-populated while others don't.

Why is this happening?

Specifically the all text fields are being remembered and pre-populated but my image file field and time weekly fields are not. They are definitely still in the database and are displayed in my show view but not pre-populated on the edit view?

Do certain types of fields not get pre-populated or what is this behavior? I would ideally like to have all of the fields pre-populated(image, dates, text, etc)

Here is my code:

Edit view:

```
<div class="editprofilebox">

    <h1>Take a moment to fill out your profile:</h1>

    <div class="container-fluid">


            <div class="edit-profile-form">
                <%= form_for @user, :html => { :role => 'form', :class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => true } do |f| %>

                    <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="row">


                        <div class= "col-sm-4">

                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder:"First Name" %>
                            </div>

                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Last Name" %>
                            </div>

                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.label :profile_image, class: "control-label" %>
                            <%= f.file_field :image, class: "profile-picture-upload" %>
                            </div>

                        </div>



                        <div class= "col-sm-4">
                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.label :twitter %>
                            <%= f.text_field :twitter, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Type your update title here" %>
                            </div>

                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.text_field :occupation, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Occupation" %>
                            </div>

                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.text_field :gender, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Gender" %>
                            </div>

                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.text_field :work_history, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Work History" %>
                            </div>

                            <div class: "form-group">
                            <%= f.number_field :years_of_experience, class: "form-control", placeholder:"years_of_experience" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                    <h3> time available </h3>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">

                                            <%= f.label :Monday %>
                                            <%= f.check_box :monday, class: "time-checkbox", placeholder:"Type your update title here" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :mondaytime1, class: "form-control time-box"%>
                                            <%= f.time_field :mondaytime2, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.label :Tuesday %>
                                            <%= f.check_box :tuesday, class: "time-checkbox", placeholder:"Type your update title here" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :tuesdaytime1, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :tuesdaytime2, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.label :Wednesday %>
                                            <%= f.check_box :wednesday, class: "time-checkbox" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :wednesdaytime1, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :wednesdaytime2, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.label :Thursday %>
                                            <%= f.check_box :thursday, class: "time-checkbox" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :thursdaytime1, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :thursdaytime2, class: "form-control time-box" %>

                        </div>
                        <div class:"col-sm-2">
                                            <%= f.label :Friday %>
                                            <%= f.check_box :friday, class: "time-checkbox" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :fridaytime1, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :fridaytime2, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.label :Saturday %>
                                            <%= f.check_box :saturday, class: "time-checkbox" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :saturdaytime1, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :saturdaytime2, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.label :Sunday %>
                                            <%= f.check_box :sunday, class: "time-checkbox" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :sundaytime1, class: "form-control time-box" %>
                                            <%= f.time_field :sundaytime2, class: "form-control time-box" %>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                      <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
                    </div>

                <% end %>
            </div>


        </div>

</div>
```

show view:

```
<div class="profilebox">

    <div class="profile-title-box" >
        <%= @user.first_name %> <%= @user.last_name %> profile
    </div>
    <hr>

<div class="profile-container">

    <div class="row ">

        <div class="profile-image-box col-sm-4" >
            <%= image_tag @user.image.thumb('150x185#').url if @user.image_stored? %>
        </div>

        <div class="profile-info-box col-sm-8">
            <%= @user.email %>
            </br>
            <%= @user.first_name %>
            </br>
            <%= @user.last_name %>
            </br>
            <%= @user.occupation %>
            </br>
            <%= @user.gender %>
            </br>
            <%= @user.work_history %>
            </br>
            <%= @user.years_of_experience %>
            </br>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<hr>

        <div class="profile-extra-box">
            <h3>Complete your profile here:</h3>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %>
        </div>


</div>
```

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "User updated successfully!"
            redirect_to user_path
        else 
            flash[:danger] = "User could not be updated!"
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end


    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :image, :twitter, :monday, :mondaytime1, :mondaytime2, :tuesday, :tuesdaytime1, :tuesdaytime2, :wednesday, :wednesdaytime1, :wednesdaytime2, :thursday, :thursdaytime1, :thursdaytime2, :friday, :fridaytime1, :fridaytime2, :saturday, :saturdaytime1, :saturdaytime2, :sunday, :sundaytime1, :sundaytime2, :occupation, :gender, :years_of_experience, :work_history)
    end


end
```

Scheema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140906225655) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "image_uid"
    t.string   "image_name"
    t.text     "twitter"
    t.boolean  "monday"
    t.text     "mondaytime1"
    t.text     "mondaytime2"
    t.boolean  "tuesday"
    t.text     "tuesdaytime1"
    t.text     "tuesdaytime2"
    t.boolean  "wednesday"
    t.text     "wednesdaytime1"
    t.text     "wednesdaytime2"
    t.boolean  "thursday"
    t.text     "thursdaytime1"
    t.text     "thursdaytime2"
    t.boolean  "friday"
    t.text     "fridaytime1"
    t.text     "fridaytime2"
    t.boolean  "saturday"
    t.text     "saturdaytime1"
    t.text     "saturdaytime2"
    t.boolean  "sunday"
    t.text     "sundaytime1"
    t.text     "sundaytime2"
    t.string   "occupation"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "work_history"
    t.decimal  "years_of_experience"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: I think you should dump some more poorly-formatted code so it's even harder to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Pre-population" has two connotations, both of which you need to consider:

> 1. Browser-based data
> 2. Server-based data

---

**Browser**

The difference here is that browser based data is basically the "remember me" stuff you type into forms on e-commerce sites and the like.

The reason I mention this is because when you have a *user* form, modern browsers (exclusing IE) will generally populate it with the relevant data you have used before. This can be seen with this [introduction to Autofill](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en-GB) on Chrome's site:

[image]

In essence, it means that if you load standard "input names" on your pages, Chrome will endeavour to populate them with data you've either saved, or inputted into other websites.

**Firstly**, you need to make sure you are not having your details inputted by the browser. If this the is the case, it will mean you've got to get the server-side functionality working regardless.

Either way, you should look at using the server-based data as described below:

---

**Server**

Secondly, you'll have sever-based data. This is *real* Rails data, and what you need in your page:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

   <%= image_tag @user.image.url if @user.image.present? %>
   <%= f.file_field :image %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

As per the [`form_for` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), if you have the correct ActiveRecord object populated, and have the data in your database, calling the attribute-based input helpers *should* populate for you.

There *are* some caveats to this, however:

--

**Image**

Using `file_field` will **not** pre-populate your image.

The [file upload](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/file) element is distinctly different to the [image](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) element - simply that the upload element cannot show you an image. This means you have to explicitly show the image in your `edit` form, if indeed you want to show it:

```
# Edit View
<%= image_tag @user.image.thumb('150x185#').url if @user.image_stored? %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

We've used this method [here](http://bvc-demo.herokuapp.com) (just sign up for free and try to upload a profile image):

[image]

Although we used JQuery heavily here, we made it so that the image form shows the image, which then gives you the ability to upload a new one.

--

**Time**

Frankly, I'm not sure about your time field.

Like the explanation above, you'll want to ensure you're using the attributes from your database to populate your time fields. I see you're using a lot of different checkboxes, which although might help create a better system, will likely not populate the data you want

Comment: Thank you so much! This is an incredibly in dept answer. I am not certain about the attributes of check boxes, it seems they behave like file fields and do not remember the data. How would you go about implementing a weekly availability schedule if not using check boxes where the data is pre-populated server side?